# Zend Guard Run-time support missing! Windows 2008 Server IIS7

Tags: iis-7, loader, guard, zend-guard

I get the "Zend Guard Run-time support missing!" page even though I have Zend Guard Loader installed and properly configured.

I have a Windows 2008 server with IIS 7 and PHP 5.4.42 which is a non-threadsafety version.

I need PHP 5.3 or 5.4 for the TemplateMonster.com template that I am trying to use.

I have added these lines to my php.ini file:

```
zend_loader.enable=1

zend_extension="C:\Program Files\ZEND\v5.4\ZendLoader.dll"
```

When I use the command php -v I get this:

```
PHP 5.4.24 (cli)(built: Jan 8 2014 20:26:10)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

Tech support at TemplateMonster suggests that the permissions need to be set properly and give me a list of linux permissions to set for specific files and folders. When I ask for Windows specific permission settings they can not help me, but confirm the template will work on a windows server. I have successfully setup the template on a test server but still cannot get the templete working on the production server. I did not set any permissions on the test server.

I have given read/write and execute permissions to the IUSR_MyServer user for the entire file set.

I have read every article I can find on this subject and am at an end to my ideas of what is wrong here. I sure hope someone can help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I had downloaded the wrong version of PHP. I downloaded the Non-threaded safety version and bingo! All is now working.